# Sum last 2 days with day data gaps in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data frame

```
| Id | Date     | Value |
| 1  | 1/1/2019 | 11    |
| 1  | 1/2/2019 | 12    |
| 1  | 1/3/2019 | 13    |
| 1  | 1/5/2019 | 14    |
| 1  | 1/6/2019 | 15    |
```

I want to calculate the sum of last 2 values by date:

```
| Id | Date     | Value | Sum  |
| 1  | 1/1/2019 | 11    | null |
| 1  | 1/2/2019 | 12    | null |
| 1  | 1/3/2019 | 13    | 23   |
| 1  | 1/5/2019 | 14    | -13  | // there is no 1/4 so 0 - 13
| 1  | 1/6/2019 | 15    | 14   | // there is no 1/4 so 14 - 0
```

Right now I have

```
let window = Window
             .PartitionBy("Id")
             .OrderBy(Functions.Col("Date").Cast("timestamp").Cast("long"))

data.WithColumn("Sum", Functions.Lag("Value", 1).Over(window) - Functions.Lag("Value", 2).Over(window))
```

With this approach I can assume that the missed value is equal to previous one (so 1/4 is equal to 1/3 = 13).

How can I consider 1/4 as zero?

Comment: Do not get the example, all 10 ten 11,12,.. Last or Earliest meant? More robust example required

Comment: @deeptowncitizen, any news ?

Comment: Is the answer correct?

Comment: @deeptowncitizen, is the answer correct ? Do you still have a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You got two ways to do this.

One would be to use `lag`function with `when` and `otherwise` and use the api data to remove one day from date.

The pros is this is working fine and quickly, the cons is that each time you to change your lag formula, you have to rewrite it...

However, I found a more generalizable method. The idea will be to fill the missing date using the `Timestamp` to `Long` and use `spark.range` to generate every possible date between `minDate` and `maxDate`

```
// Some imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Our DF
val df = Seq(
(1, "1/1/2019", 11),
(1, "1/2/2019", 12),
(1, "1/3/2019", 13),
(1, "1/5/2019", 14),
(1, "1/6/2019", 15)
).
toDF("id", "date", "value").
withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy"))


// min and max date
val (mindate, maxdate) = df.select(min($"date"), max($"date")).as[(Long, Long)].first
// Our step in seconds, so one day here
val step: Long = 24 * 60 * 60

// Generate missing dates
val reference = spark.
  range(mindate, ((maxdate / step) + 1) * step, step).
  select($"id".cast("timestamp").as("date"))

// Our df filled !
val filledDf = reference.join(df, Seq("date"), "leftouter").na.fill(0, Seq("value"))

/**
+-------------------+----+-----+
|               date|  id|value|
+-------------------+----+-----+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|   1|   11|
|2019-01-02 00:00:00|   1|   12|
|2019-01-03 00:00:00|   1|   13|
|2019-01-04 00:00:00|null|    0|
|2019-01-05 00:00:00|   1|   14|
|2019-01-06 00:00:00|   1|   15|
+-------------------+----+-----+
*/

filledDf.
  withColumn("result", F.lag($"value", 1, 0).over(windowSpec) - F.lag($"value", 2, 0).over(windowSpec)).show

/**
+-------------------+----+-----+------+
|               date|  id|value|result|
+-------------------+----+-----+------+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|   1|   11|     0|
|2019-01-02 00:00:00|   1|   12|    11|
|2019-01-03 00:00:00|   1|   13|     1|
|2019-01-04 00:00:00|null|    0|     1|
|2019-01-05 00:00:00|   1|   14|   -13|
|2019-01-06 00:00:00|   1|   15|    14|
+-------------------+----+-----+------+
*/
```

Comment: The example does not look valid with all the 10's does it not? @BlueSheepToken

Comment: I think the idea of the problem is just "how to fill value of missing date", because, yeah, the example is absolutely not relevant. I have seen you asked for clarifications, thanks for that ! I will probably just wait for the clarifications

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks for commenting instead of downvoting ! :)

Comment: Qjestion is very vague but filling the data gaps is valid